# my simple code is not working

Tags: javascript, html

my very simple html code, actually my javascript code is not working, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function write(){
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "hello world";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" onclick="write()">hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to change the `<div>` content to "hello world". but when i try to do it, when i click the `<div>` element, its content is erased and it gives me a blank page. what am i doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

That happens because 'write' is already defined as a method from the document object. You need to change the name of the method to something else.